# how to pass selected item to api vujes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console

how to pass selected item from select option field to api.in vuejs

```
<select :v-model="selectedRole" class="custSelect"  >
    <option v-for="option in options"
            v-bind:value="option.value">
        {{option.role}}
    </option>
</select>
```

below is my script

```js
const SignupData={
    occupation:this.selectedRole
}

axios.post('http://34.61.88.0:3000/api/newuser',SignupData)
   .then(function(response) {
     console.log("dds",SignupData)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 'v-model' can be set for options.
or
 `const SignupData={
    occupation:this.selectedRole.value
}`

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your params in a object, you have two options:

with desctructoring of your `SignupData` **const**

```
axios.post('http://34.61.88.0:3000/api/newuser', {
    ...SignupData,
})
```

or

```
axios.post('http://34.61.88.0:3000/api/newuser', {
    occupation: this.selectedRole,
})
```